# How to check a single rule with ansible-lint?

Tags: ansible

How do I check just the `yaml: truthy value should be one of [false, true] (truthy)` and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth value check is part of the `yamllint` checks wrapped in `ansible-lint`. You can execute just the `truthy` check by executing:

```
yamllint --config-data "{rules: {truthy: enable}}" .
```

Check the [documentation](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#custom-configuration-without-a-config-file) for further options.